# How can set logo to left-corner and menu to right-corner in a single row?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I wanted to set my menu like below image.I rearranged my codes in many ways to solve this problem.But every time i failed.The right section of this menu is creating a gap in right area.Please help me to solve this problem.

[image: LIKE_THIS]
**HTML CODE:**

```
<div class="col-xs-12 bigMenu">
    <div class="col-xs-2 logo">
      <a href="#"><img src="images/logo2.png" alt="Brainwave"/></a>
    </div>
    <ul class="col-xs-10 list-unstyled list-inline">
      <li class="current"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

**CSS CODE:**

```
    .header-area .bigMenu {
        background: transparent;
    }
    .header-area .bigMenu:after {
        content: "";
        clear: both;
        display: block;
    }
    .header-area .bigMenu .logo {
        float: left;
    }
    .header-area .bigMenu ul {
        list-style: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        float: right;
    }
    .header-area .bigMenu ul li {
        font-size: 1.2rem;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        letter-spacing: 0.2em;
        padding: 0 1rem;
    }
    .header-area .bigMenu ul li a {
        display: block;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #ffffff;
        padding: 0px 20px;
        font-size: 1.2rem;
        letter-spacing: 0.2rem;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add this style sheets to your CSS:

```
.col-xs-10 {
    display: block;
    float: right;
}
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/19x5t86a/2) is demo.

```css
.header-area .bigMenu {
    background: transparent;
}

.header-area .bigMenu:after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: block;
}

.header-area .bigMenu .logo {
    float: left;
}

.header-area .bigMenu ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: block;
}

.header-area .bigMenu ul li {
    display: block;
    float: right;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 0.2em;
    padding: 0 1rem;
}

.header-area .bigMenu ul li a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 0px 20px;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    letter-spacing: 0.2rem;
}

.col-xs-10 {
    width: auto;
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-xs-12 bigMenu">
    <div class="col-xs-2 logo">
      <a href="#"><img src="images/logo2.png" alt="Brainwave"/></a>
    </div>
    <ul class="col-xs-10 list-unstyled list-inline">
      <li class="current"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: It is working now.But i want to know why it was not working without "width: auto"....will you please help me to understand?

Comment: @TanvirRahman yes, you also can `display: block` yours `<li>` and then `float: right` them. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/19x5t86a/2).

Comment: @TanvirRahman ah, thats because your `ul` get the width as it needs, and in Bootstrap default value of `.col-xs-10` it's "width: 83.3%" and it takes the whole width.

Comment: One more thing your updated answer will move "Home" to right.But in main menu "Home" is in left........:)

Comment: @TanvirRahman I don't how to explain this, you need to understand `position` more deeply, you will get this with some practice. To fix this, just make "Home" last in your list:)